# URL redirect in apache2 .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

how can i redirect redirect url from

`http://www.mydomain.com` to `https://mydomain.com`

and

`https://www.mydomain.com` to `https://mydomain.com`

or all subdomain with our without `https` except `status.mydomain.com` to redirect to `https://mydomain.com`?

Example: `hello.mydomain.com` and `https://hello.mydomain.com` to `https://mydomain.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is help you

> Redirect 302 http://www.mydomain.com https://mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^status\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes it definitely will .

Comment: its not working `https://www.mydomain.com/` to `https://mydomain.com/` all the others are working.. maybe because it's `https` and your condition is `HTTP_HOST` which will only work on all non-https.

Comment: That is simply not correct. `HTTP_HOST` variable works in both conditions. You have some local config issue. Just make sure your SSL site's DocumentRoot is same as `non-https` one and this rule is **very first rule**

Comment: it's now working.. i just add `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^www\.gremdev\.com  [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*) https://gremdev.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: i think i need to delete cache on my browser to check if its working without the condition i made in my comment

Comment: Well rule doesn't say anywhere to not to make it work in Firefox. Rule is same for all the browsers. Clear browser cache in Firefox and retry.

Comment: it's not also working google chrome.. use your code above.. all browser works on anything in the url except on `https://www` to `http://` @anubhava

Comment: As I said rule doesn't distinguish from browser A to browser B so it has to be some local conduit you have in coffee may be or simply caching issue which I can't guess from outside.